# Query to insert ids into another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table **Approvals**

```
+----+----------+
| ID |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Approved |
|  2 | Rejected |
|  3 | On Hold  |
+----+----------+
```

I store the "id" of table Approvals in another table **Budget** which is as follows:

```
+-----+-----------+--------+
| BID | RequestID | Status |
+-----+-----------+--------+
| 101 |   2228484 |      1 |
| 102 |   3834848 |      2 |
+-----+-----------+--------+
```

`1 = Approved`
`2 = Rejected`

I am importing the Budget data from an excel spreadsheet which contains the Approvals Status in text form. Example below

```
+-----+-----------+----------+
| BID | RequestID |  Status  |
+-----+-----------+----------+
| 101 |   2228484 | Approved |
| 102 |   3834848 | Rejected |
+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Is there a way for me to fetch the relevant status ids for the excel import from table Approvals and insert it into the table Budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Budget (BID,RequestID,Status)
SELECT i.BID, i.RequestID, a.ID as Status
FROM Import_Table i
INNER JOIN Approvals a
  ON i.Status = a.Name
```

Comment: Please elaborate: try to avoid posting code-only answers.